# Back/restore single environment in Octopus Deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

We've been experimenting with Octopus Deploy on a development PC and now want to transfer the environment we've created onto our main Octopus Deploy server (which is used by other teams and already has a few environment set up on it).

So we would like to backup/restore this one environment. However, it looks like Octopus only allows you to [backup/restore the entire database](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/configuration/backuprestore).

Is it possible to move a single environment from one Octopus server to another using backup/restore or another means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was simply doing the following in order:

- Shutting down Octopus service so that no transaction going through.
- Copy the raven database (usually stored in Program Files\Data) to your new server.
- Install the new Octopus server and during the setup, in the Storage Tab, specify the location of your data location copied in the second step above.

The Octopus developer, Paul, mentions the great thing about RavenDB is the installation. It requires no services running like SQL. It's just a copy paste of the data itself and great for installation and portability.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to backup/restore just part of the database - you'd need to restore a full backup, and then delete the information you don't need.

Octopus 2.0 (which is now a public beta) has a comprehensive REST API so it would be possible to use that API to fetch a subset of information and import it to your new Octopus server.